# Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows failure in vcpkg

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

I have a problem trying to install anything with vcpkg. The installation terminates after printing the following message: Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows, no matter what package or triplet set (I tried any combination of cpu and platform.)

In some places the proposed solution is clearing the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun. I don't have that AutoRun set in my machine.  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling vcpkg, CMake and Visual Studio. Installation in disk C or D (in the logs X=D:\Dev) gives the same result.

```
PS X:\Libraries\vcpkg> .\vcpkg.exe install eigen3:x64-windows
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
eigen3[core]:x64-windows -> 3.3.9
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows...
PS X:\Libraries\vcpkg>

PS C:\vcpkg> .\vcpkg.exe install eigen3:x64-windows
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
eigen3[core]:x64-windows -> 3.3.9
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows...
PS C:\vcpkg>

PS X:\Libraries\vcpkg> .\vcpkg.exe install eigen3:x64-windows --debug
[DEBUG] Feature flag 'binarycaching' unset
[DEBUG] Feature flag 'manifests' unset
[DEBUG] Feature flag 'compilertracking' unset
[DEBUG] Feature flag 'registries' unset
[DEBUG] Feature flag 'versions' unset
[DEBUG] BuiltinRegistry initialized with: ""
[DEBUG] Using vcpkg-root: X:\Libraries\vcpkg
[DEBUG] Using installed-root: X:\Libraries\vcpkg\installed
[DEBUG] BuiltinRegistry initialized with: ""
[DEBUG] Using buildtrees-root: X:\Libraries\vcpkg\buildtrees
[DEBUG] Using downloads-root: X:\Libraries\vcpkg\downloads
[DEBUG] Using packages-root: X:\Libraries\vcpkg\packages
[DEBUG] Using scripts-root: X:\Libraries\vcpkg\scripts
[DEBUG] Using ports-root: X:\Libraries\vcpkg\ports
[DEBUG] Using versions-root: X:\Libraries\vcpkg\versions
[DEBUG] Default binary cache path is: C:\Users\dbalc\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives
Computing installation plan...
[DEBUG] Found path: D:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe
[DEBUG] CreateProcessW("D:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" --version)
[DEBUG] cmd_execute_and_stream_data() returned 0 after 28654 us
[DEBUG] CreateProcessW("D:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DVCPKG_ROOT_DIR=X:/Libraries/vcpkg -DPACKAGES_DIR=X:/Libraries/vcpkg/packages -DBUILDTREES_DIR=X:/Libraries/vcpkg/buildtrees -D_VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR=X:/Libraries/vcpkg/installed -DDOWNLOADS=X:/Libraries/vcpkg/downloads -DVCPKG_MANIFEST_INSTALL=OFF -P "X:\Libraries\vcpkg\buildtrees\0.vcpkg_tags.cmake")
[DEBUG] cmd_execute_and_stream_data() returned 0 after 23484 us
The following packages will be built and installed:
eigen3[core]:x64-windows -> 3.3.9
[DEBUG] CreateProcessW("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -all -prerelease -legacy -products * -format xml)
[DEBUG] cmd_execute_and_stream_data() returned 0 after 22588 us
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows...
[DEBUG] CreateProcessW("X:\Libraries\vcpkg\downloads\tools\git-2.26.2-1-windows\mingw32\bin\git.exe" --version)
[DEBUG] cmd_execute_and_stream_data() returned 0 after 21343 us
[DEBUG] CreateProcessW("X:\Libraries\vcpkg\downloads\tools\powershell-core-7.1.0-windows\pwsh.exe" --version)
[DEBUG] cmd_execute_and_stream_data() returned 0 after 229347 us
[DEBUG] CreateProcessW(cmd /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" -vcvars_ver=14.2 amd64 2>&1 <NUL & echo cdARN4xjKueKScMy9C6H & set)
[DEBUG] cmd_execute_and_stream_data() returned 255 after 684084 us
[DEBUG] C:\A\1\70\s\src\vcpkg\base\system.process.cpp(592)
[DEBUG] Exiting after 1048604 us (1039935 us)
PS X:\Libraries\vcpkg>
```

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: Apparently it is a bug in VS 16.10 Preview 2. Here is a workaround. I just downgraded to 16.9 https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/13890#issuecomment-832642742